# What is the best grafting knife?

Tags: trees, pruning, technique, grafting

Help me choose the best grafting knife, **right know i have the draper 76777** (the first photo) but it is a single edged knife. I am between those grafting knives in the photos, if you recommend something else let me know! Also should i sharpen the blades of the knives? The knife will be mainly used to graft fruit trees like citrus. Is it worth to give $40 for the victorinox in the last photo?

[image: The one i have now]
[image]
Or one of these?[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There is usually no "best", in any thing. You should describe your use, to see what it is best for you (species and type of grafting). A knife for roses is very different than "omega [as form of the letter] scissors" for vines, or a knife for Prunus trees.

Comment: i want it to graft citrus mostly and generally fruit trees. My type of grafts will be bark grafting and T budding

Comment: Grafting knives are normally flat on one side, which I assume is what you mean by "only cuts from one side" - you sharpen them like a chisel - flat side flat, bevel meets the flat side. You certainly don't want a double-edge blade, that makes it hard to put pressure on the back of the blade with your thumb. If you need a lifter for T-Budding you can whittle one or get one separate from your knife-only knife.

Comment: @Ecnerwal yes it is flat on the one side, that is what i don't like on the grafting knife of the first photo, because a knife is always better to cut on both sides for obvious reasons, especially when you want to shave a scion for bark grafting, it is harder to do it backwards

Comment: I have to think you have a technique or preconception issue. If it was obviously better to have a double-bevel on a grafting knife, that's how they would be made. Likewise, I don't understand what you think has to be done "backwards" when using a single-bevel knife. Unfortunately, this is not something that the internet excels in helping with - hands-on is much better, and even then there can be gaps in understanding - but I wonder how you learned, and suspect you are doing something in an unusual way compared to standard techniques. You can cut bevel-up or bevel down, for one thing...

Comment: I cannot explain everything from chat, maybe you did not even understand my point. Watch this video to understand at that time: https://youtu.be/bEsgiOspZhA?t=440 . You cannot do it with single edged knife unless you do it with the left hand. Did you get my point?

Comment: All grafting/budding knives have a single beveled/sharpened side and flat on other side. I think its because you don't want it to cut too deep (and hence slice your skin off your fingers :) ). It also sounds correct that you want some friction and you are going back and forth creating a tongue on whip and tongue grafts and hence don't want it to cut through like butter (and hence cut your skin again). I use mostly the Felco Victorinox knives which are around $20, but also there are some Carbon Steel options that are supposedly better starting at $40/50 (and up to Tina brand which costs $150).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bought Swiss victorinox grafting knife and it is extremely sharp and great tool.

Answer (score 3):

I am a new grafter but the Felco Victorinox was recommended to me as good quality knife to use as it keeps a good edge without constant sharpening and is very durable. I have one now.

Comment: is this double edged?